# Excel 2007 & SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I am looking for a script or ideas on how to Quickly and efficiently import data from Excel 2007 Into a temp table in SQL Server Mangement Studio 2008?
(I have win xp)

1. I have a table in an Excel file (XLtest.xlsx) that contains two Column (Column X) and (Column Y) in sheet (shTest).
2. Want to import excel table to my database (test) in SQL as a temp table (temp table).
3. Find the table (Mobi) in the database (test) and Column (Column X2)
4. Replace the values ​​in (Column X2) with values ​​from (Column Y) when the values ​​of (Column X2) equal to the values ​​of (Column X).

   Wishing all a happy new year.
   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your tasks will be best and easiest accomplished with a SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) package.  You can learn more about SSIS here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx

Comment: Hi Shark,
I do not have it. I have already bought the program SQL Server Management Studio. do you have any suggestions for solution in the application server management?